# A question on Groups and Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm studying Abstract Algebra and I need to construct a cyclic extension of order $2^5 3^4 5^{10}$. I have no idea of how to do that. Could someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: So you essentially need to find an integer $n$ such that that number divides $\phi(n)$, since then you can take a subfield of the $n$th cyclotomic field.

Comment: The ground field is not specified in the question, so there is much freedom in a sense.

Comment: @Nishant However, subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is not always cyclic. So, just by taking subfield of $n$th cyclotomic field will not be enough.

Comment: You're right. But if $n$ is prime, it is cyclic, and there are infinitely many primes congruent to $1$ modulo any integer.

Comment: Since the ground field is not specified, an approach is using the fact: Finite fields have cyclic extension of any degree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $2^53^45^{10} + 1$ is prime (at least according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E5%2a3%5E4%2a5%5E10%20%2b%201%20prime)).

If we let $\zeta_n$ denote a primitive $n$th root of unity, then the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$, which is a splitting field of $f(x) = x^n - 1$, has a Galois group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$.

When $n$ is prime, then it is a theorem that $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$.

Comment: Great answer. How did you know it was prime ?

Comment: WolframAlpha :P

Comment: I don't think WolframAlpha was supposed to be used :p

Comment: Maybe, but for numbers *that* large, I don't think it was a coincidence that (big number) + 1 was prime.  I'd certainly be interested in seeing a different cyclic construction.

Comment: An idea to avoid WolframAlpha, is the Dirichlet theorem on primes in arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 4):

You can look into finite fields. If $q$ is a prime power, then the extension $\Bbb F_q \subset \Bbb F_{q^N}$ is cyclic of order $N$ (it's generated by the $q$th power automorphism $x \mapsto x^q$).

So you can just pick $q=2$ and $N = 2^5 3^4 5^{10}$